# How can I create a function that takes in a string and then generates an unique hash every iteration?

Tags: python-3.x, api, hash

Im looking for a function that creates a more or less random string, which then can be used to authenticate a users api call through the header in a request.

I came up with:

```
import hashlib
import time
import random
from datetime import datetime

def createKey(eMail):
    hash = hashlib.sha1()
    hash.update(str(datetime.now()).encode('utf-8'))
    hash.update(eMail.encode('utf-8'))
    time.sleep(random.randrange(0, 2, 1))
    hash.update(str(datetime.now()).encode('utf-8'))
    return(hash.hexdigest())
```

Using a loop, I could see that some of the keys are duplicates:

```
for x in range(10000):
    print(createKey('me@mail.com'))
```

Output:

```
d355003c38000845ec08c4d69edc95e42e54fc57
d355003c38000845ec08c4d69edc95e42e54fc57
d355003c38000845ec08c4d69edc95e42e54fc57
003a51edea4fa392d26a18837f4509fe63cdcdb1
5865c9e6e902eba0ec33b65ae65e40774c2e7498
73bf67ebca8fdacd56247f0a937ee53898bde9e3
73bf67ebca8fdacd56247f0a937ee53898bde9e3
163d9c435c85c6b5d14c345e1be4b20e3346ff25
790f0b1b833b969484d69642d05bc60ce611cedd
e99e67410b260112c891eb913b329bd5254afd54
4d4451ea98f61932b7c221c067cbb01217dab10a
...
```

I was hoping that using datetime.now() would give me enough granularity to result in a different hash, but obviously Im wrong. Also pseudo random sleeper was supposed to increase entropy.

How can I improve my approach to create a function that takes in an string(email) and then generates an unique hash every iteration?

Comment: Change `time.sleep(random.randrange(0, 2, 1))` to `time.sleep(random.randrange(1, 2, 1))`. What would be the use case for such a function? Since you're not storing the datetime when the hash is produced it gets really hard to derive the same hash again. In which case you could just create a random token each time and forget about email and datetime alltogether. It would be easier and probably more secure.

Comment: Yea setting the sleep to 1 sec minimun is a option, but after experimenting a bit I really don't find it very functional. My initial thought was to create an api key for a potential user upon registration using his email and the current datetime. But I think you are right. I think Im going to use the secrets lib to create a token.